# Cannot add foreign key constraint MySql Error

Tags: mysql, key, addition

i've a school project and i'm trying to execute my sql script and i've this error

> ## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Here's my table who generate this error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Visiteur` (
    `id` char(4) NOT NULL,
    `nom` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `prenom` char(30)  DEFAULT NULL, 
    `login` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mdp` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `adresse` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cp` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ville` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `dateEmbauche` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `idRang` char(2)NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`idRang`) REFERENCES Rang(`idRang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here my references table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Rang` (
    `idRang` char(2) NOT NULL,
    `nomRang` char(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idRang`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Sorry for my english, i'm french
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your statements seem to be correct. Might sound silly but are you creating the table "Rang" before creating "Visiteur" right?

Comment: http://stefanomartines.com/gsb_sql.txt   Here's my sql script

Comment: Yes, "Rang" is before "Visiteur"

Comment: Another silly question, what's the default storage engine of your DB? Could it be that even that you're trying to create your tables in InnoDB, they are being created as MyISAM? I've run your SQL script locally and it worked flawlessly